# Sharing state between processes using agents in Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, agent

I have one HTTP endpoint which creates a map and stores it using Agent.

I want to access this map when I hit another endpoint. but when I a trying to get the data from Agent it is returning empty.

Can someone please confirm if this is a valid scenario for using Agents ? If yes, What am I missing ?

Code :

```
defmodule BoardState do
  use Agent

  def start_link do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def add(game_id, board) do
    Agent.update(__MODULE__, fn state ->
      Map.put(state, game_id, board)
    end)
  end

  def reset do
    Agent.update(__MODULE__, fn _state -> %{} end)
  end

  def get(game_id) do
    Agent.get(__MODULE__, fn state ->
      Map.get(state, game_id)
    end)
  end

  def getKeys() do
    Agent.get(__MODULE__, fn state ->
      Map.keys(state)
    end)
  end

  def name() do
    Agent.agent()
  end
end
```

Code from where agent is started

```
`defmodule TicTacToe.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      TicTacToeWeb.Endpoint
    ]

    **BoardState.start_link()**

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: TicTacToe.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

  def config_change(changed, _new, removed) do
    TicTacToeWeb.Endpoint.config_change(changed, removed)
    :ok
  end
end
```

I have also tried this with Genserver, but when I hit 2nd enpoint I am not able to get data stored in 1st endpoint

Comment: At first blush this seems correct. Perhaps the problem is with how you're starting your agent? Have you added it to your supervision tree or are you perhaps calling `start_link` in your HTTP endpoint?

Comment: Is this application running on a single node? `Agent` is not distributed. The share the data between nodes you need either a separate store, like DB, or Redis, or [tag:mnesia].

Comment: @Pawel Obrok  - I am running agent when I am starting the server .

Comment: Its on same node. But the book says agent can be distributed .

This is from the book , "programming in Elixir 1.6"

Making It Distributed  Agents and tasks run as OTP servers, so they are easy to distribute—justgive our agent aglobally accessible name. That’s a one-line change:            ​       @name {​:global​, __MODULE__}        Now we’ll load our code into two separate nodes and connectthem. (Remember that we have to specify names for the nodes so they can talk.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code from this repo https://github.com/sayali-kotkar/tic_tac_toe on Elixir 1.9. Your code looks acceptable. This is working for me or I'm misinterpreting the problem.

1st request:

```
curl -X POST localhost:4000/game
```

1st response:

```
{
   "board":{
      "Cell(1, 1)":"empty",
      "Cell(2, 1)":"empty",
      "Cell(3, 1)":"empty",
      "Cell(1, 2)":"empty",
      "Cell(2, 2)":"empty",
      "Cell(3, 2)":"empty",
      "Cell(1, 3)":"empty",
      "Cell(2, 3)":"empty",
      "Cell(3, 3)":"empty"
   },
   "game_id":67,
   "status":"success"
}
```

2nd request:

```
curl -X PUT localhost:4000/game/67 \
--header "Content-Type:application/json" \
--data '{"player_id":0, "row": 1, "column": 2}'
```

2nd response:

```
{
   "board":{
      "Cell(1, 1)":"empty",
      "Cell(2, 1)":"empty",
      "Cell(3, 1)":"empty",
      "Cell(1, 2)":0,
      "Cell(2, 2)":"empty",
      "Cell(3, 2)":"empty",
      "Cell(1, 3)":"empty",
      "Cell(2, 3)":"empty",
      "Cell(3, 3)":"empty"
   },
   "game_id":67,
   "status":"success"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code for the `BoardState` module almost verbatim, except I changed `start_link` so that it plays better with the `Supervisor` API:

```elixir
defmodule BoardState do
  ...

  def start_link(_) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> %{} end, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  ...
end
```

I added `BoardState` to my supervision tree:

```elixir
defmodule Test.Application do
  ...

  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      TestWeb.Endpoint,
      # Notice I'm putting BoardState under a supervisor here.
      # In your case, you linked it to the process performing the startup,
      # which is a different thing.
      BoardState
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Test.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end

  ...
end
```

I then added a simple controller to test it:

```elixir
defmodule TestWeb.PageController do
  use TestWeb, :controller

  def put(conn, params) do
    BoardState.add(params["key"], params["value"])
    Plug.Conn.resp(conn, 200, "OK\n")
  end

  def get(conn, params) do
    value = BoardState.get(params["key"])
    Plug.Conn.resp(conn, 200, "#{value}\n")
  end
end
```

And a couple of routes for that:

```elixir
defmodule TestWeb.Router do
  ...
  scope "/", TestWeb do
    ...
    get "/put/:key/:value", PageController, :put
    get "/get/:key", PageController, :get
  end
end
```

With that, it seems to work as expected, remembering the data sent to it:

```sh
rindr:test yapee$ curl localhost:4000/put/hello/world
OK
rindr:test yapee$ curl localhost:4000/get/hello
world
```

I hope you can debug your problem using these snippets. I think your problem might be related to how you're not really putting your `BoardState` under supervision, but randomly `start_linking` it instead.

Comment: Thanks Pawel. Code I have written is working on iex and also when I run the tests but when I do it using endpoint it fails.
https://github.com/sayali-kotkar/tic_tac_toe